# Ripple Emulator does not creating any .COD package for blackberry 6& 7

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I add the ripple emulator through google chrome
I enable the ripple emulator through google chrome
I have a more doubts on this place. I install the  BLACK BERRY Web-works sdk from this link: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/. Is this web-works SDK is supported for blackberry 6,7 environment & 10?

BlackBerry 10 Environment native structure is getting from web-works sdk.     Blackberry 10 is building successfully. so Blackberry 10 .For creating a bar package I followed total procedure by using blackberry web-works sdk web-tool. So BAR FILE is created successfully

So I have a doubt on Blackberry 6 & 7 Environment .[In mobilefirst platform foundation 7.0 blackberry 6 & 7 environment is created and build successfully ,But it does not asking any environment variables for web-works_home

so I am following through ripple emulator for creating .cod package?

Ripple emulator extensions from google chrome is not working fine. Is not showing start or stop services . I want to create .cod file. Please suggests some steps for Blackberry 6 & 7 environment structure.

Comment: In work-light 7.0 .At the time of building Blackberry 6&7 Environment is not asking any web-works_home environment variable but its build successfully.By using command bbwp.exe archive-folder ,I get the .cod file. I manually created the archive-folder.App is launching successfully. ,but it is not connected to the server.I checked one line in config.xml is <access sub-domains="true" uri="*"/> .I changed to My work-light server host also.But It fails to connecting to the server.I am using web-works sdk for BB6&7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a more doubts on this place. I install the BLACK BERRY Web-works sdk from this link: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/. Is this web-works SDK is supported for blackberry 6,7 environment & 10?

The links clearly mention only BlackBerry **10**, hence it is only supported for BlackBerry **10**.

If you want to build a .cod file for your BlackBerry **6 & 7** then you need the WebWorks SDK for BlackBerry **6 & 7**.

Have you read the following tutorial, which instructions how to install the correct SDK? https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/setting-up-your-development-environment/setting-blackberry-6-7-development-environment/

Delete your current SDK installations and follow the instructions in the tutorial above and the tutorials that follow it.

Comment: In work-light 7.0 .At the time of building Blackberry 6&7 Environment is not asking any  web-works_home  environment variable but its build successfully.By using  command  bbwp.exe  archive-folder ,I get the .cod file.  I manually created the archive-folder.App is launching successfully. ,but it is not connected to the server.I checked one line in config.xml  is  <access sub-domains="true" uri="*"/> .I changed to My work-light server host also.But It fails to connecting to the server.I am using web-works sdk for BB6&7